# Gulp watch runs once then fails

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have a project using Gulp and SASS and when I run `gulp watch` it runs the first change successfully without any issues.

The problem occurs when I make any further changes - they seem to not register and are seemingly ignored.

Here is my Gulpfile.js code:

```js
var theme_name = 'project-theme';

var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    sass    = require('gulp-sass'),
    concat  = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify  = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename  = require('gulp-rename');

var paths = {
  styles: {
    src: 'wp-content/themes/' + theme_name + '/gulp/sass/theme.scss',
    folder: 'wp-content/themes/' + theme_name + '/gulp/sass/*.scss',
    dest: 'wp-content/themes/' + theme_name + '/assets/css/'
  },
  scripts: {
    src: 'wp-content/themes/' + theme_name + '/gulp/jquery/*.js',
    dest: 'wp-content/themes/' + theme_name + '/assets/js/'
  }
};

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.styles.src, {
      sourcemaps: true
    })
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(rename({
      basename: 'main',
      suffix: '.min'
      }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.scripts.src, {
        sourcemaps: true
    })
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dest));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.scripts.src, gulp.series('scripts'));
  gulp.watch(paths.styles.folder, gulp.series('styles'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('styles', 'scripts', 'watch'));
```

I've looked at other similar questions on Stack Overflow and they've not provided me with any success. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. What I now understand is that Gulp does not know that the task is finished, therefore ignoring all further changes.

In order to fix this I changed Line 48 & 49 to this:

```js
gulp.watch(paths.styles.folder).on('change',gulp.series('styles'));
gulp.watch(paths.scripts.src).on('change', gulp.series('scripts'));
```

All additional changes are now registered by `gulp watch`.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.